# How to dynamically choose field to return in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic-sql

I have a Ruby on Rails application, and I would like to be able to dynamically choose what field to return to the database.  Here's what I mean:

Suppose I have a database table called Dog and that table has fields of "id", "name", "color".

If I want to get dog #7s name, I could obviously just do:

```
d = Dog.find(7)
the_output = d.name
```

However, what I want to do is dynamically choose what field to return for dog #7.  So suppose that I have defined:

```
the_field = "name"
```

I want to be able to do something like call:

```
d.(the_field)
```

and have it return the name of the dog.  (I use parenthesis here, because in MATLAB you can do it this way  (and I do all the time) and it works, but that doesn't work in Rails.)  The obvious advantage to this is that I can then somewhere else in the program set `the_field = "color"` and have my same code return the color of the dog instead of the name.

I tried doing this:

```
Dog.find(d.id, :select=>the_field)
```

but that returns a Dog object, not just the string containing the name of the dog.  And since, in the code, I don't know which field is being called, I'm not sure how to extract just the string containing the field that I want.

So hopefully that all made sense, and hopefully some kind person knows how to do this.

Thanks!

Q

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.query_field(id, field)
    find(id).send(field)
  end
end

field = :name
Dog.query_field(7, field) # "Roscoe"
field = :color
Dog.query_field(7, field) # "brown"
```

Comment: Ahha!  The `send()` command is exactly what I needed.  Brilliant.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For rails activerecord objects you can do:

```
field = :name
d = Dog.find(7)
d[field]
```

You for a whole group of objects you can do

```
field = :name
Dog.where(some_sql_query).pluck(field)
```